# Is there a proper way to make generic crud functions for Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to implement Generic Crud Operations in Swift for Core Data. This is an issue I am having while creating data. I have been somewhat successful but I cant figure out a way to add relationships between entities in a generic way.

I am new to Core Data and I have also searched for an answer but I haven't been able to find any. Please guide me if I am looking at it a wrong way.

My entities are:

User and Movies, where User has a one to many relationship with Movies.

[User and Movies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dxj1.png)

Current function to achieve this:

```
   func createData<T>(forEntity entity: Entities, andObj objArr: [T]) {
    
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entity.rawValue, in: managedContext)!
    
    for obj in objArr {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
        let container = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        
        for child in mirror.children  {
            var shouldSkip = false
            for entityLocal in Entities.allCases {
                if child.label!.lowercased() == entityLocal.rawValue.lowercased(){
                    shouldSkip = true
                    if let childArr = child.value as? [Any] {
                        createData(forEntity: entityLocal, andObj: childArr)
                    }
                }
            }
            if !shouldSkip {
                container.setValue(child.value, forKey: child.label!)
                shouldSkip = false
            }
        }
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Where Entities are:

```
enum Entities: String, CaseIterable {
 case User   = "User"
 case Movie  = "Movies"
}
```

And I mimicking an api call and calling the function like:

```
var movies = [MovieModel]()
var users = [UserModel]()

for _ in 1...3 {
    let movie = MovieModel(title: "Man of Steel", rating: "9/10")
    movies.append(movie)
}

let user = UserModel(username: "Khan", email: "khan@example.com", password: "12345", movies: movies)
users.append(user)
        
CoreDataManager.sharedManager.createData(forEntity: Entities.User, andObj: users)
```

My Core Data Movies Table is:

[Movie Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wfkt.png)

The issue is, that users and movies are saved in their respected tables, but I want to have user's ID in the foreign key of movies as well. Please guide me and also let me know if I am looking at it the wrong way. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is, that users and movies are saved in their respected tables, but I want to have user's ID in the foreign key of movies as well.

The first thing you need to do is to stop thinking of Core Data as if it were a SQL database. It's not designed to work the same way, and trying to use it like SQL will make things difficult for you. Core Data uses SQLite internally, but its API is not SQL-like.

You don't use foreign keys in Core Data, you use relationships. You already have the relationship you need, so that's what you would normally use with Core Data. If you have a `Movies` instance and you want to know what `User` goes with that movie, you use the `user` relationship that you already have. To make that work, you need to assign a value for the relationship when you create an instance. When you create a `Movies`, assign a value to the `user` relationship. A foreign key isn't necessary, because the relationship exists.

If you prefer to use a SQL-like approach, there are several open source SQLite wrappers available, for example [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) and [PLDatabase](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/pldatabase).